# Using keyboard or gaming USB pedals as MIDI sustain pedal

Tags: windows, midi, input-devices

I am searching for how to use available devices as a sustain pedal.

Is there ready to use software with low latency that can handle input and translate it to midi?

Or C#,C++ example how to send MIDI messages in respond of user input.

I found sustain is

MIDI CC 64

with value 0 to 63 = Off, 64 to 127 = On

Comment: Hi ! did you find a solution ? If so, please explain how... Thanks

Comment: No. For on/off key now i am using simple takt switch button in carboard holder. For range i think photoresistor-based solution with arduino ATmega32U4 or with any midi controller is good. If interesting - i will finish it, as i now understood how to control wah-pedals in reaper VST

Comment: Wow... does it click click click ? xd... I ended up buying a better piano. Thanks for answering !

Answer (score 1):

[Bome MIDI Translator Pro](https://www.bome.com/products/miditranslator) can translate many input sources (MIDI, keyboard, serial port) into MIDI messages. You'd have to check whether your gaming USB pedal works with it.

The Windows MIDI API does not allow applications to create MIDI ports, so you probably also need to install a virtual MIDI port driver.